# An error occurred (NoSuchChange) when calling the GetChange operation

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, sed, jq, aws-cli

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Update the DNS

RECORD=$1
if [ -z "${RECORD}" ]; then
    echo "Please provide a valid record (URL endpoint)"
    exit 1
fi

ID=$(aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id ZONEID --cli-input-json "{\"HostedZoneId\":\"Z1R8UBAEXAMPLE\",\"ChangeBatch\":{\"Changes\":[{\"Action\":\"UPSERT\",\"ResourceRecordSet\":{\"Name\":\"www.domain.tld.\",\"Type\":\"CNAME\",\"TTL\":300,\"ResourceRecords\":[{\"Value\":\"${RECORD}\"}]}}]}}" | grep "/change/" | cut -c 15- | sed -e 's/"//g' | sed 's/\(.*\),/\1 /'))
echo "Change ID: ${ID}"
aws route53 get-change --id ${ID} | grep INSYNC
while [ $? -ne 0 ]
do
    echo "WAITING FOR DNS TO UPDATE... PLEASE WAIT"
    sleep 5s
    aws route53 get-change --id ${ID} | grep INSYNC
done
```

For some reason, the `ID` returned appends a `,` at the end, even though I have explicitly removed it with `| grep "/change/" | cut -c 15- | sed -e 's/"//g' | sed 's/\(.*\),/\1 /')`

I also tried `| jq -r '.ChangeInfo.Id'` but the `,` is still being appended to `ID`

What am I missing?

Any advice is much appreciated

Comment: What is the JSON output of your `aws route53` command?. Why do you have to complicate the JSON storage in double quotes and escape it? Use single quotes  - `'{"HostedZoneId":"Z1R8UBAEXAMPLE","ChangeBatch":{"Changes":[{"Action":"UPSERT","ResourceRecordSet":{"Name":"www.domain.tld.","Type":"CNAME","TTL":300,"ResourceRecords":[{"Value":""}]}}]}}'`

Comment: from the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/change-resource-record-sets.html#output it is a JSON object

Comment: Then `| jq -r '.ChangeInfo.Id'` should work fine as expected. Are you incorrectly piping the output of `jq` again back to `sed`? Please post the JSON output, without that, its hard to explain why you are seeing the problem

Comment: `{
 "ChangeInfo": {
     "Status": "PENDING",
     "SubmittedAt": "2020-10-16T10:45:56.841Z",
     "Id": "/change/C0155693NNXR37X9226V"
 }
}
`
So yeah `jq -r '.ChangeInfo.Id'` should work, but for some reason it is appending a `,`

Comment: That can't possibly happen, unless you still have the `sed` command piped to jq's output like you originally posted

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simplify this by using the [`--output` option](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html), as well as the [`wait` command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/wait/resource-record-sets-changed.html)

You could do something like this (not tested)

```sh
ID=$(aws route53 change-resource-record-sets \
    --hosted-zone-id ZONEID \
    --cli-input-json "{\"HostedZoneId\":\"Z1R8UBAEXAMPLE\",\"ChangeBatch\":{\"Changes\":[{\"Action\":\"UPSERT\",\"ResourceRecordSet\":{\"Name\":\"www.domain.tld.\",\"Type\":\"CNAME\",\"TTL\":300,\"ResourceRecords\":[{\"Value\":\"${RECORD}\"}]}}]}}" \
    --query 'ChangeInfo.Id' \
    --output text)

aws route53 wait resource-record-sets-changed --id $ID
```